# unable to read kafka messages but can list the available topics

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to connect locally from IntelliJ IDEA to kafka in k8s on minikube and read some messages. I can list the available topics with the consumer but am unable to read any messages.

The consumer code:

```java
public class TestConsumer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer-test");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());

    consumer.listTopics().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("topic = " + key));

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test"));

    try {
      while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1L));

        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
          System.out.println(record.offset() + ": " + record.value());

        consumer.commitAsync();// doesn't work with or without this line
      }
    } finally {
      consumer.close();
    }
  }
}
```

For installing in k8s I have used this helm chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka with the following configuration

```yaml
replicaCount: 3
deleteTopicEnable: true
metrics:
  kafka:
    enabled: true
```

k8s services:

```sh
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE

kafka                      ClusterIP      10.97.216.82     <none>        9092/TCP                     30m
kafka-headless             ClusterIP      None             <none>        9092/TCP,9093/TCP            30m
kafka-metrics              ClusterIP      10.107.104.199   <none>        9308/TCP                     30m
kafka-zookeeper            ClusterIP      10.101.103.6     <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   30m
kafka-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP      None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   30m
```

k8s pods:

```sh
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

kafka-0                                  1/1     Running   4          32m
kafka-1                                  1/1     Running   4          32m
kafka-2                                  1/1     Running   2          32m
kafka-client                             1/1     Running   0          31m
kafka-exporter-6ccc69f8cc-tgnxh          1/1     Running   0          33m
kafka-zookeeper-0                        1/1     Running   0          33m
```

(only the kafka-client pod was manually created and not by the helm chart)

I am using this dependency of kafka `compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.7.0'`

As addition to the setup I run:

```sh
kubectl port-forward kafka-0 9092:9092
```

and add this line in my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local kafka-headless
```

Creation of the topic:

```sh
./kafka-topics.sh --create \
--zookeeper kafka-zookeeper:2181 \
--replication-factor 1 \
--partitions 1 \
--topic test
```

Producing on the topic

```sh
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic test
```

I am able to read all the messages with the console consumer though

```sh
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What does "can not read" mean? What error do you get?

Comment: Port forwards are not enough https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/. + Your terminal is using `kafka:9092` to connect, not `127.0.0.1:9092`, so these are in fact, different connections

Comment: @daniu none, it's just that `records` is empty on every iteration

Comment: Are there exception messages on client or server? You usually need to set a key/value decoder in your properties (not sure if it defaults to ByteArrayDecoder though).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys! I finally managed to read messages from kafka.

@OneCricketeer points where the problem was and I found a similar link which explains the problem very well https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

What I did was to port forward `kafka-0-external` on port `9094` service and change the values for the helm chart to

```yaml
replicaCount: 3
deleteTopicEnable: true
metrics:
  kafka:
    enabled: true
externalAccess:
  enabled: true
  service:
    type: NodePort
    port: 9094
  autoDiscovery:
    enabled: true
serviceAccount:
  create: true
rbac:
  create: true
extraEnvVars:
  - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
    value: "CLIENT://:9092,INTERNAL://:9093,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094"
  - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
    value: "CLIENT://:9092,INTERNAL://:9093,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094"
  - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
    value: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
```